# Wrongly labels in legend of ggplot2 using scale_color_manual with data from multiple geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I want to display several sets of curves in the same ggplot.
That part works fine, but when I compare the curves with the
content in the plot legend, the order seems to be changed 
(so that the red and green annotations match the green and red curves).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

ggplot() + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 8)), aes(area, color='1')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 4)), aes(area, color='4')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 2)), aes(area, color='16')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 1)), aes(area, color='64')) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-10, 10)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Number of samples', 
                      values =c('1'='black', '4'='red', '16'='green', '64'='blue'), 
                      labels = c('1', '4', '16', '64'))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the labels, are sorted lexicographic. ('1', '16', '4', '64').
With this fact in mind, the labels can be changed to ('01', '04', '16', '64').
This is a bit cumbersome, but generates the plot I want.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

ggplot() + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 8)), aes(area, color='01')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 4)), aes(area, color='04')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 2)), aes(area, color='16')) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = data.frame(area = rnorm(5000, sd = 1)), aes(area, color='64')) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-10, 10)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Number of samples', 
                      values =c('01'='black', '04'='red', '16'='green', '64'='blue'), 
                      labels = c('01', '04', '16', '64'))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).